# How do I include counts of named tables in the output of an oracle stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which selects rows into an out cursor, like so:

```
PROCEDURE GetUserTables(
    out_cur    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN out_cur FOR
        SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, ut.table_name
          FROM users u
          JOIN user_tables ut ON ut.user_id = u.user_id
      ORDER BY u.user_name, ut.table_name;
END
```

The `table_name` column in `user_tables` contains the name of a DB table, and I'd like to include the counts those tables in the output; so `out_cur` would contain something like this:

```
| user_id | user_name | table_name   | row_count |
+---------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
| 1       | Simon     | simons_dogs  | 1         |
| 1       | Simon     | simons_cats  | 0         |
| 2       | Jenny     | jennys_dogs  | 2         |
| 3       | Ellie     | ellies_dogs  | 3         |
| 3       | Ellie     | ellies_cats  | 1         |
| 3       | Ellie     | ellies_birds | 5         |
```

Where `simons_dogs` etc.. are names of actual tables.

My first thought was to have a table variable inside the procedure, and to loop through user_tables inserting into it, then to join to it in my select; but I can't work out how to have a multicolumn table variable.

Comment: Dynamic SQL, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

Comment: Do you need approximation on row count or the exact row count?

Comment: Exact row count.  My problem isn't that I can't get the count, it's that I can't get it into the output cursor.

Comment: An approx count I can see (pull from stats easily), but an exact count at runtime will get ugly with large tables w/o a pk or unique idx.  This probably falls under "do you really need this?" category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Dynamic SQL, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm

You will need two queries:

- In an outer query you will need to query the table names you are interested in querying.
- The inner "count(*)" query will be constructed as a string, embedding the name of the table. While normally bind variables should be used, they can't be used for the table names (or column names) parts of the query.

This is the normal approach, but doesn't seem to fit the example code you've provided. In this case, you could make a function which accepts a table name, and inside the function use Dynamic SQL to perform the count(*), something like this:

```
function count_rows(p_table_name in varchar2) return integer is
  l_count integer;
begin
  execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || p_table_name into l_count;
  return l_count;
end;
```

and used like

```
select table_name, count_rows(table_name) as row_count
from user_tables;
```

Comment: Thanks.  How do I collect the results of the inner query into the output cursor?

Comment: I just updated the answer suggesting the use of a function to do this.

Comment: Getting there, I think.  I now get "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" when I run my SP.

Comment: Ah, there's a stray quote.  I'll fix the answer.  Thanks!